# Tomcat - deployed .war file does not show

Tags: web-server, tomcat, deployment

I'm running a TomCat 7.0.11 everything worked fine, till I deployed a new `.war` file. 
Using the manager the only message I get is

> OK

but after refreshing the List of Applications no App appears. The TomCat tells me

> `.war` file already exists

if trying to redeploy the `.war`

I'm not able to figure out where the problem is. Is it possible that my installation of TomCat is not compatible with Java 7?

Comment: what have you found out when reading the `catalina.out` log?

Answer (score 0):

It was a compatibility problem. Updating the TomCat did the thing. Now TomCat v. 7.0.40 is running  on my server and everything works fine!